# How do I create a Json list from an Entity object then pass it via a view model in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a many-to-many relationship between `tblContent` and `tblSubContent` (joined by `tblContentSubContent`.

I have also set up a View Model thusly:

```
public class ContentViewModel
{
    public tblContent content { get; set; }

    public string templateName { get { return content.ContentTypes.TemplateName; } }

    public tblContent nextFile { get; set; }

    public tblContent previousFile { get; set; }

    public string subContentList { get; set; }

}
```

I would like to populate the `string subContentList` above with a key/value pair from my `tblContent.tblContentSubContent` data and serialize it into JSON so that I can loop through it with JS in my view.

I have not had much luck getting started with this.  I did try to serialize the data using code from another post:

```
 var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 viewModel.subContentList = serializer.Serialize(viewModel.content.ContentSubcontent);
```

Sadly, this results in `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet1`

Am I close?  I am not even sure what code I should post here to help answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be better ways to go about this whole thing, I was able to make the above strategy work by simply drilling farther down into my `ContentSubContent` relationship when serializing:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
viewModel.subContentList = serializer.Serialize(viewModel.content.ContentSubcontent.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).Select(x => x.Subcontent.SubcontentId));
```

The result is not a key/value array, but a list of IDs (`[3584,3586,3587,3588,3589,3590,3591,3592,3593...]`) but that will work for me even better I suppose.

A better approach if any would be appreciated.  I am too new to c# to know what is "right."